# SQL Developer 'run script' failing but 'run statement' works

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a simple left join query on two tables linking to get the description:

```
SELECT WORK.ACTION_ID, WORK.ACTION_STAT, WORK.DESCRIPTION_ID,
  WORK.CLIENT_SERVER_IND, WORK.UPDATE_TSTAMP, WORK.UPDATE_USER_ID,
  WORK.OTHER_ACTION_DATA, D.DESCRIPTION_ID, D.LANGUAGE, D.DESCRIPTION_TEXT,
  D.UPDATE_TSTAMP DSCRP_UPD_TSTAMP
FROM xxxx.R_ACTION WORK
INNER JOIN xxxx.R_DESC_TEXT D ON WORK.DESCRIPTION_ID = D.DESCRIPTION_ID
WHERE D.LANGUAGE = 'ENGLISH'
AND D.DESCRIPTION_STAT = 'P';
```

I have the query in SQL Developer and if I select 'Run Statement' it works fine in less than a second and I can retrieve all 283 records.

If I select 'Run Script' I can see the output for about 33 lines and it then just hangs and eventually I get a 'socket read timed out' message.

I have the same table in a different schema, but with slight different data in it, and in that one the run statement and run script work fine.

Why would it work for 'Run Statement' but fail for 'Run Script' in this schema?

Comment: You said it's a 'left [outer] join' query, but you've shown an inner join. Not sure if it matters but might be helpful to clarify that in case. Since the statement works it looks like a SQL Developer issue, or possibly a network issue, but you could check the alert log too. What version of SQL Developer are you using? How many results are displayed at a time in the 'Query output' pane - less than 33? And can you add the table definitions - wondering if any of the columns are CLOBs. The socket error makes me think the network is closing the link on you because of something in the data.

Comment: Also, 'Run Script' would seem to imply a series of statements, maybe with a BEGIN/END, rather than just one select.

Comment: i think Alex is onto something, if not clob then maybe some binary chars in the data you're pulling.  When you run as a script, the output is dumped to the Script output window (basically a text file), while the run statement populates a table (Query Result tab).

Comment: Which Oracle DB version (11.2.0.3)?  Which SQL Developer version (4.0.80)?  Does the query complete without error in SQL*Plus?

Comment: What are the data types involved? Any 'wide' columns there? Alex's question about CLOBs is where I'm going too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the `CLOB` bandwagon, too.  Thinking 90% chance your `DESCRIPTION_TEXT` is a `CLOB` field.

As a test, try this query as "run script", which ignores the actual `DESCRIPTION_TEXT` and outputs "bogus" instead:

```
SELECT WORK.ACTION_ID, WORK.ACTION_STAT, WORK.DESCRIPTION_ID,
  WORK.CLIENT_SERVER_IND, WORK.UPDATE_TSTAMP, WORK.UPDATE_USER_ID,
  WORK.OTHER_ACTION_DATA, D.DESCRIPTION_ID, D.LANGUAGE, 'bogus' DESCRIPTION_TEXT,
  D.UPDATE_TSTAMP DSCRP_UPD_TSTAMP
FROM xxxx.R_ACTION WORK
INNER JOIN xxxx.R_DESC_TEXT D ON WORK.DESCRIPTION_ID = D.DESCRIPTION_ID
WHERE D.LANGUAGE = 'ENGLISH'
AND D.DESCRIPTION_STAT = 'P';
```

If that works, try using this query, which makes use of `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR()` to help cast the CLOB as VARCHAR by truncating output to first 4000 characters of it.

```
SELECT WORK.ACTION_ID, WORK.ACTION_STAT, WORK.DESCRIPTION_ID,
  WORK.CLIENT_SERVER_IND, WORK.UPDATE_TSTAMP, WORK.UPDATE_USER_ID,
  WORK.OTHER_ACTION_DATA, D.DESCRIPTION_ID, D.LANGUAGE,
  dbms_lob.substr(D.DESCRIPTION_TEXT, 4000) DESCRIPTION_TEXT,
  D.UPDATE_TSTAMP DSCRP_UPD_TSTAMP
FROM xxxx.R_ACTION WORK
INNER JOIN xxxx.R_DESC_TEXT D ON WORK.DESCRIPTION_ID = D.DESCRIPTION_ID
WHERE D.LANGUAGE = 'ENGLISH'
AND D.DESCRIPTION_STAT = 'P';
```